# CORS error on posting file upload form from browser to firebase but no error from postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, file-upload

I have built a Node app with admin SDK and deployed it to Firebase. it has an API endpoint for uploading file via POST method and Form data in post's body.

Problem is: everything works when i send the request from Postman, but posting from browser instantly fails with CORS policy. in firebase console log is see `Function execution took 1206 ms, finished with status: 'crash'` and no other detail.

In the backend i already have `app.use(cors({ origin: true }))` and other posts with json body work just fine from browser. which make me think this CORS error might not actually be CORS?

when I check the request header from the network part of inspect tools it has `content-type: multipart/form-data`

Am i not constructing my request right in the front end (REACT)?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext";
import Recorder from "../components/Main/Recorder";

const NewAudio = (props) => {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth();

    const isComment = props.location.state.status;
    let threadId;
    if (isComment) {
        /** If the new audio is a comment, a threadId is associated to it */
        threadId = props.location.state.threadId;
    }
    const [audioDetails, setAudioDetails] = useState({
        url: null,
        blob: null,
        chunks: null,
        duration: {
            h: null,
            m: null,
            s: null,
        },
    });

    function handleAudioStop(data) {
        console.log(data);
        setAudioDetails(data);
    }

    function handleAudioUpload() {

        // POST endpoint
        const targetUrl =
            "<my URL>";

        // Creation of the FormData object
        let newAudioData = new FormData();


        // Form data formatting and other details to post the form.
        let audioTitle = document.getElementById("audioTitle").value;
        let tags = document.getElementById("audioTags").value;
        let audioTags = tags.split(", ");
        let userid = currentUser.userId;
        let password = currentUser.password;
        let audioFileName =
            audioTitle.replace(/\s+/g, "-") + "_" + userid + "_" + Date.now();

        // Addition of data to the FormData object
        newAudioData.append("audioTitle", audioTitle);
        newAudioData.append("audioTags", JSON.stringify(audioTags));
        newAudioData.append("userid", userid);
        newAudioData.append("password", password);
        newAudioData.append("file", audioDetails.blob, audioFileName + ".ogg");

        // POST REQUEST
        fetch(targetUrl, {
            method: "POST",
            body: newAudioData,
            
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    function handleReset() {
        const reset = {
            url: null,
            blob: null,
            chunks: null,
            duration: {
                h: null,
                m: null,
                s: null,
            },
        };
        setAudioDetails(reset);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {isComment ? "Comment for thread " + threadId : "New thread"}
            <Recorder
                audioDetails={audioDetails}
                setAudioDetails={setAudioDetails}
                handleAudioStop={handleAudioStop}
                handleAudioUpload={handleAudioUpload}
                handleReset={handleReset}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default NewAudio;
```

in postman the request looks like this and works great:
[image]

Request headers:
[image]

Error in console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As i suspected it was not really a CORS problem.
the problem was that i was trying to set a wrong key names:

```
// Addition of data to the FormData object
       newAudioData.append("audioTitle", audioTitle);
       newAudioData.append("audioTags", JSON.stringify(audioTags));
```

where as my application was expecting 'threadTitle' and 'threadTags'.

so changing them to their correct form solved the problem:

```
// Addition of data to the FormData object
       newAudioData.append("threadTitle", audioTitle);
       newAudioData.append("threadTags", JSON.stringify(audioTags));
```